# Missing content in ASP.NET Core (Blazor) Azure publication

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side

I'm writing a Blazor POC and deploying to Azure (linux service app).

Using the standard template (with counter etc) I create a basic web app BUT with a SQLite database in the root of the project.

- I run it up in dev mode and it works
- I publish to a folder and run it...it works.
- I publish to my Azure app and it doesn't work, it won't connect to the SQLite database file

I connect to my azure app via SFTP to investigate and notice that the SQLite database file just isn't there.

(It IS in my local "folder" publication)

If I copy the file over via ftp, my application works!

Currently I have in the root folder of the project marked as "Content" and "Do not copy"

Any ideas? (this all quite new to me)

(I have set up an Azure pipeline to do this also, but it seems to not publish the SQLite database in the same way).

I've now read
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-7.0 and there does seem to be some boiled in logic to do with json files but I cannot see a simple way to publish a non json file (there's a very complex description that if you google the main element you will find 3 references on the whole internet.

Sadly i can also put complete rubbish in my project file and publish and nothing complains, so i'm a bit stuck, sometimes i see in some answers/docs an attribute CopyToPublishDirectory, but intellisense seems to encourage me to use an element

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="AppData/*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

It seems to be incredibly difficult just to tell the publication process...I want to publish file X to exactly the folder it is in my project....thats it.

(for other reading this my only workaround at the moment is to publish the application using publish, but to manually deploy the files it wont publish using filezilla)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Missing content in ASP.NET Core (Blazor) Azure publication

Whenever we create any additional files in the existing Application, they are not included directly by default.

***Check the Workaround for the same.***

I have created a `Blazor Server App`.

- As `appsettings.json` exists by default in the application, you can check the Properties of the file.
- Select `appsettings.json` => click `f4` key, Properties window will be opened.

[image]

- Initially the Build Action will be `Content` and `Output Directory` will be `Copy if newer`   for the default created `config`/`Data` files.
- This means that the file will be included in the Publish on the initial deployment.
- If it is set to `copy always`, then the file will be included in every deployment.
- If the `Output Directory` is set to  `Do not copy` the specific file will not be included in the build and will face the same issue which you have right now.

[image]

- It is advised to select `Copy always` if your Data file has frequent changes/updates.
- As you have mentioned it is `SQLite database`, there can be frequent updates in the DB, so it is better to make the `Output Directory` to `Copy always` to get all the changes without any issues.

> i can also put complete rubbish in my project file and publish and nothing complains

Whenever you change the properties of files, it will get reflected in the `.csproj` file.

There is no problem with the snippet which you have in `.csproj` file.

The snippet just says about including the file.

Here Iam changing the `Copy if newer` to `Copy always`, you can see the entry is added in `.csproj` file.

```cs
<Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

- Change the property of the file which you are missing to `Copy always` , build and re-deploy the App.

### Update:

> but I think if you applied your technique to an .xml file, and published to azure (i.e. something that creates a .zip) you will find it isnt included

I have added one sample `.xml` file under `AppData` folder and deployed to Azure Linux App Service.

[image]

***My `.csproj` file settings:***

```cs
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="AppData\XMLFile.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="AppData\XMLFile.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

- I can see the file available in the deployed App.
- Open the `Bash` from `DebugConsole` => Navigate to the `wwwroot` folder and run `ls` command to see the deployed files.

[image]

Comment: sadly I think this does apply to .json files but not to other types of files. I'll try, but I think if you applied your technique to an .xml file, and published to azure (i.e. something that creates a .zip) you will find it isnt included.

Comment: Ok..Will check with `.xml` and let you know.

Comment: Apart from file missing are you getting any error ?

Comment: Your `CopyToPublishDirectory` is set to `Always1`.Are you sure the value is correct? set it to `Always` and check once.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd - Please check the updated section in the answer.

Comment: hello....hmmm....u are publishing using visual studio publish?

Comment: Yes..Iam publishing from VS using Publish Option.

Comment: it works...frankly I don't understand!....maybe my problem was reading the docs. Let me write an answer to summarise, I'll refer to you as the person who deserves the credit, or add your own answet and I'll mark it as correct...give me 10 mins

Comment: actually I've just marked your answer as the answer. For some reason I was focussing on CopyToPublishDirectory AND as i was adding the instructions manually I think i was ommiting to include "<None Remove="AppData\XMLFile.xml" />", frankly the files are a bit of a mystery to me. But lots of thanks.

Comment: Yes,few settings or missing in your `.csproj` file, you might have removed it unknowingly.

Comment: I did...everytime VS put the Remove line in, I'd remove it, I don't really understand what it does, but it was pretty stupid for me to think i knew better than VS about something i clearly didnt understand, thanks again, I've also now discovered kudulite thanks to you