# msbuild ignoring CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" in asp.net (blazor) project file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

It seems by default various 'patterns' of files are published, in particular wwwroot/**, **/*.razor.js, and it seems that we CAN suppress publication of these files by using CopyToPublishDirectory.

(I've tried it out by using a JSON file, and then preventing it being published)

I can also control what is copied to the output directory by using CopyToOutputDirectory.

This, oddly is used when I publish my app to a local folder, and seems to work correctly.

If I try to force the publication process to include a file in the .zip file (in my case for an azure app publication), then its ignored.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="TextFile.xml" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

This wont be included.

If I turn diagnostics on (I'm using VS profesional), I can see the msbuild finding my setting

```
1>            TextFile.xml
1>                    CopyToOutputDirectory=Never
1>                    CopyToPublishDirectory=Always
```

I can see it selecting the file as a candidate

```
1>    Task Parameter:
1>        CandidateAssemblyFiles=
...
1>            wwwroot\XMLFile.xml
```

I can see it rejecting it as it goes through its various globbing patterns

```
1>    Rejected asset 'TextFile.xml' for pattern 'wwwroot/**'
```

I can then see it 'preparing for build', but magically the 'CopyToPublishDirectory' property seems to have vanished (or at least thats my guess).

```
Target "PrepareForBuild" in file "C:\...Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "....csproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
    Task "FindAppConfigFile"
    : Task Parameter:
PrimaryList=
    ...
    TextFile.xml
            CopyToOutputDirectory=Never
    Properties\launchSettings.json
            CopyToOutputDirectory=Never
            CopyToPublishDirectory=Never
            ExcludeFromSingleFile=true
    ...
    wwwroot\css\bootstrap\bootstrap.min.css
            CopyToOutputDirectory=Never
            CopyToPublishDirectory=PreserveNewest
            ExcludeFromSingleFile=true
```

and then it never appears.

Comment: Hi, what is the actual type(project template) of "asp.net (blazor) project"? Do you mean "Blazoe WebAssembly App"? Different type of projects may have different performance when setting CopyToPublishDirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered by

[Missing content in ASP.NET Core (Blazor) Azure publication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589696/missing-content-in-asp-net-core-blazor-azure-publication)

I'm not sure I understand the project settings, but the setting described in that answer work for me.